# web.config.CLR4 file

Tags: asp.net

What is the use of web.config.CLR4 file in asp.net web application ? To be specific i came across it while examining tools developed by infragistics i.e in netadvantage product which provides tools like grid view, tab, tree view for developing web applications. As well  please help me with step wise solution to develop a tool from the scratch in asp.net using c#.

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully deploy your `ASP.NET` project to IIS you need web.config appropriate for the target CLR, thus there are different web.config files for `CLR2` `CLR35` and `CLR4`.